# If LED's have different bin codes, how can I know what I am buying?

Tags: led, brightness

I will start by confessing I am a hobbyiest engineer (ie: still in school) and thus am open to allegations my concerns are not terribly important.  However, I have this:

I was looking at page three of the binning codes for some Cree L.E.Ds ([here)](http://www.cree.com/~/media/Files/Cree/LED%20Components%20and%20Modules/XLamp/Data%20and%20Binning/XLampXPE2.pdf) and a quick look suggests the maximum brightness ranges from "23" lm to "164" lm - though if you look at: page 5 of [this](http://www.cree.com/~/media/Files/Cree/LED-Components-and-Modules/XLamp/Data-and-Binning/XLampXPE2.pdf), you might notice there is a much smaller range for the red ones I am interested in - 56.8 to 80.6. I'll assume this is typical, but significant...

I am in fact trying really hard to build a really bright bicycle light, so I much care about lumens per watt and visible flux.

Do real companies guaranteeing brightness in portable light have to calibrate their electronics to compensate for different batches (or even within batches), or wield their bulk buying power to get similar components?

Better yet, my supplier will simpler tell me what bin they happen to have. Is there a way for a consumer to *reliably* get ahold of a particular bin?

Comment: I know that for high quality machine vision system backlights the LEDs are graded by the backlight manufacturer for colour and intensity. I've seen white backlights made of standard LEDs that look fine when lit up - they all looked the same - but by putting a sheet of office paper over them to reduce the intensity I could clearly see differences in intensity and colour. Don't get too hung up on this. Remember to weight the benefit of all your trouble against the cost of a larger battery.

Answer (score 2):

As shown in pages 3 through 5, specific bins have specific order codes. Simply [use that code when ordering devices from a distributor](http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en?keywords=XPEBRD-L1-0000-00901) and you will get devices from within that bin.

Comment: ...No  ****, as they say.  I probably should've gotten more sleep before I tried to figure this out.